# Setting text box value without changing ng-model.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, user-interface

I have a text box that will be used as a search input. I want to have text display to indicate what field that box will search, but when clicked on/in and the user sets a value the default text goes away. You've probably also seen this when filling out forms where the label is inside the box until you start typing. How do I do this without screwing up the ng-model?

Answer (score 1):

`<input placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" />`

placeholder will have the indication text, and ng-model to handle it in js files.
and do not pre define ng-model in js file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [placeholder attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder)

> A hint to the user of what can be entered in the control .

```html
<input placeholder="some infomational text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `placeholder`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Some text" />
```

Or:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{ bindedVar }}" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvSQQ/127/)

> The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field